# Is my contribution to corporate housing tax deductible?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, deduction

My residence is in NY but my company moved me to CA for a temporary assignment (one year).  They are providing corporate housing but I still have to contribute approximately $900/month.   Is the $900/month tax deductible?

Comment: Do they pay the landlord directly for their part? What does the $900 cover?

Comment: This is actually a surprisingly complicated situation - the best I can figure at the moment is "maybe": https://www.corporatehousing.com/blog/corporate-housing-tax-deductible/ The corporation providing housing can be considered a taxable fringe benefit, but possible excluded and your expenses can potentially be deducted, but it depends on if you can establish a "tax home" in NY according to IRS regulations: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p463